# WSE 3.0 + X509 + java

Tags: java

Actually I have to work with a web service written in .NET with WSE 3.0 and digital signature and encryption of soap messages. I have to make a java client in order to consume the .net webservice.

I have the wsdl file, a CA.cer file, a certoencrypt.cer file from the provider and I would like to know where to start in order to make the java client so it can consume the web service.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about wse 3.0, but that should have no limitation on creating a client to call the web-service from java.  Generally, you should start by creating web-service proxy classes using something like [JAX-WS RI](http://jax-ws.java.net/) (I'd recommend this since its packaged with JDK 1.6) or [Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/).  Another useful tool for web-services development is [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/).

From within soap ui, you can generate the above mentioned proxy classes using a variety of web service frameworks including the 2 mentioned above.  once you have those classes generated, your going to want to reference them from your project and use them to make your web-service calls.  there are examples of how to do this all over the internet, and the implementation details will depend on the framework you choose to use.